# Temp Dir is not accessible phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Upon trying to establish a connection with phpMyAdmin Im getting the error:

```
The $cfg['TempDir'] (./tmp/) is not accessible. phpMyAdmin is not able to cache templates and will be slow because of this.
```

I have looked on here at some solutions and I am still confused.

Do I need to create a new tmp folder within `phpmyadmin` and make it executable. Does a tmp folder need to be nested in `xamppfiles/share`

How do I resolve this.

Comment: It seems you have a configuration setting that's pointing to `./tmp` (relative to the current dir) when you probably want it to point to `/tmp` (absolute) instead. (Unless perhaps `./tmp` actually does exist, in which case it might just be a permissions issue.)

Comment: a config setting where??

Comment: No idea, wherever `$cfg` gets populated from.

Comment: I don't know what you mean

Comment: ./tmp/) is not accessible. how do I make this accessible in laymen terms

Comment: Save yourself some trouble by using [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/en) instead. Very lightweight and practically zero-config.

Comment: this phpmyadmin running me ragged. not enjoying it

Comment: I believe config settings are in config.inc.php.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was having this same issue on update to phpMyAdmin 4.8.0.1.
Without changing permissions or adding any folders, you should open your `$PMA-DIR/config.inc.php` and edit the following section:

```
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
```

Add `$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';` to the file. I made mine look like this:

```
/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';
$cfg['TempDir'] = '/tmp';
```

If you already had this entry in your `config.inc.php` then make sure that the entry is correct.

Refresh phpMyAdmin in the browser and the error should be cleared.

Comment: OMG! So easy! Thnx! I spoiled so much time trying solve this!

Answer (score 2):

do `mkdir tmp && chmod 777 tmp` inside your phpmyadmin dir

then update config.inc.php file add

```
$cfg['TempDir'] = 'tmp';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XAMPP, you should ask them directly (or tag that instead); since it's designed as an integrated solution it should come with the recommended folders already configured or instructions on how to do so yourself.

However, on the phpMyAdmin side, the error message pretty much covers it: you have to create a folder with the name 'tmp' inside the phpMyAdmin installation. From a security standpoint, you should restrict this folder as much as possible to prevent other local users from being about to access these cached files, but if you're just working on your own local system then the attack vector is rather small. https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_TempDir has some more information.

So yes, go ahead and create the 'tmp' folder inside the phpMyAdmin installation.

Comment: Indeed, this is the recommended way. To explicit the steps, create the 'tmp' folder and set its exclusive user to the webservice user :
`mkdir PHPMYADMIN_DIRECTORY/tmp`
`chown www-data:www-data PHPMYADMIN_DIRECTORY/tmp`
`chmod 700 PHPMYADMIN_DIRECTORY/tmp`